# Composer require takes very long to download modules

Tags: 8, composer

I am seeing that it takes a very long time to download a module via composer. For example I just tried to require the Stage File Proxy Module on a brand new Drupal project created from [Drupal Project Template](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) and it took around 9 minutes.

```
 2016-07-08 22:31:53 ☆  Alberts-MacBook-Pro in ~/www/d8
± |master ✓| → composer require drupal/stage_file_proxy:8.*
./composer.json has been updated
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    1/6:  http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015-10$4808a9ff7f19ac4170168746ed24f8694f9e5a0799c355e26375ce90725a8828.json
    2/6:  http://packagist.org/p/provider-latest$4cfacf88e4e332a9850bd06a12ceeedf743ffac37097fdb03d8a8b6d08a0b0da.json
    3/6:  http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015$f56365502d2bdac013de2da3ae50e3df33103e9c86fd7092fe072d0e4cfc0efd.json
    4/6:  http://packagist.org/p/provider-2014$dadae06a2b0889e9967e732c6861aae8f5c4df363fdb3829bea92e2b76acbd38.json
    5/6:  http://packagist.org/p/provider-2016-04$b2962d9a234c8a0c67c152f6a5197b3a4e41ce384da5bb0c9cc7404d31e7ebe9.json
    6/6:  http://packagist.org/p/provider-2016-01$c7705812f13e96daf6bc63fbb870fda9e082bf53e3b49fcdee5088002aa8d5a7.json
    Finished: success: 6, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 6
  - Installing drupal/stage_file_proxy (8.1.0-alpha1)
    Loading from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles

 2016-07-08 22:40:45 ☆  Alberts-MacBook-Pro in ~/www/d8
```

I have seen coworkers have this same issue so it definitely isn't my machine.

I do have [Prestissimo](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo) installed.

Is everyone else seeing this same slowness?

**Update**

Ran composer clear-cache and reran with -vvv: http://pastebin.com/6xTYB0sd. This time it took 7 minutes.

Ran composer clear-cache and reran with --prefer-dist -vvv: http://pastebin.com/g6BtTMzy  This took around 5 minutes.

Comment: Maybe try some of the answers to this similar Q [Why updating of dependencies in composer is so slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413788/why-updating-of-dependencies-in-composer-is-so-slow)

Comment: Do you have xdebug enabled? Disable it and try again

Comment: One thing that helps is to use PHP 7 if you can.

Comment: @Clive Xdebug is disabled.

Comment: This is probably caused by slow internet connection. I suggest running the composer command with -vvv to see exactly what it is doing.

Comment: @Eyal I reran and pasted my output above. Can you let me know if you see anything wrong with the output?

Comment: Have you tried what @NoSssweat suggested?

Comment: @Eyal Yes just tried with --prefer-dist. Added pastebin above.  It went down to 5 minutes. Still kind of high don't you think?

Comment: Composer require and composer update are rarely used, so I wouldn't worry about it too much. Make sure that you add the composer.lock file to  version control (git/svn) and use composer install. It will be much faster.

Comment: @Eyal I guess during early development we do add a lot of modules so it eats up a lot of time.  I love composer but with Drush if I needed a module I would get it right away.